# MUIDataTable I want to hide checkbox but also i want row data when i click on rows

Tags: mui-datatable

i am doing this but onRowClick is not working

```
<MUIDataTable
        data={tableData}
        columns={tableCols}
        options={{
          search: true,
          fixedHeader: true,
          selectableRows: 'none',
          selectableRowsOnClick: true,
          displayRowCheckbox:false,
          onRowClick:this.getRow,
          customToolbarSelect: () => {},
        }}
      />
```

is there any option to hide check also and geting row data also

Answer (score 5):

You can hide this if you pass `selectableRows: false` in options props.
for more details follow the [documentation](https://github.com/gregnb/mui-datatables#options).

```
<MUIDataTable
  title={"Employee List"}
  data={data}
  columns={columns}
  options={{
    selectableRows: false // <===== will turn off checkboxes in rows
  }}
/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try adding this:-

```
selectableRows: "multiple",
selectableRowsHideCheckboxes: true,
selectableRowsOnClick: true,
```